# TypeError: 'ball' object is not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop

I am making a game where I have a cannon that shoots balls coming from the air, so I created a class named ball and a list named balls which (obviously) contains balls. Each ball has a value and every time it is hit by a projectile, it's value is decremented by one, so if the ball.value gets down to one, when hit the ball will be removed from the list and another ball must come in. Here's the code for that:

```
for projectile in projectiles:
    for ball in balls:
        if hypot(ball.rec.center[0]-projectile.center[0],ball.rec.center[1]-projectile.center[1] ) < ball.radius:
            if ball.value == 1:
                balls.remove(ball)
                balls.append(ball((randint(1,SCREENWIDTH - 100),10),2,0))
            else:
                ball.shrink()
            projectiles.remove(projectile)
            break
```

when I do this, the moment the ball is dead, I get a message saying:

```
TypeError: 'ball' object is not callable
```

but when I put `balls.append(ball((randint(1,SCREENWIDTH - 100),10),2,0))` just after the balls list initialization,I get no error but another ball just show up on the screen.
I̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶p̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶`̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶b̶a̶l̶l̶o̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶b̶a̶l̶l̶s̶`̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶e̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶r̶o̶v̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶.̶

Comment: What is `ball((randint(1,SCREENWIDTH - 100),10),2,0)` meant to do?

Comment: First argument is a tuple with x,y coordinates of the ball, second argument is the ball speed on the x axis and the second is the ball speed on the y axis. So it is meant to create a new ball object. here's the class call if that makes more sense:
`class ball:
    def __init__(self,coordinates,speedx,speedy):`

Comment: But the name `ball` is being used to define a class and also is the name of each ball when you iterate over the list of `balls`. Python doesn't know you want to create a new object.

Comment: That actually worked thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ball(x, y)` command is supposed to create an an instance of the `ball` class. But the word `ball` is already used for the element of `balls`. So, just make your loop
`for b in balls`. Using the same name for the class and an instance of the class is a really really really bad idea.

Comment: It's also a bad idea to modify the list of balls whilst iterating over it. Asking for trouble.